# undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::get_current_path_api(std::str

Tags: c++, reference, undefined

Merry Christmas, everyone.

Yesterday  I download the Boost library. i use CodeBlocks (with Mingw32 gcc V4.4.1)
 to compile it. The bjam command line is :
bjam install --toolset=gcc--prefix="C:\zjc\PluginFramework\boost_1_42_0" --build-type=complete.
 and it is successful. 
and i want to test the library. i write some code as follow:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::wcout;
using std::endl;
#include <string>
using std::string;
using std::wstring;

#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem/path.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem/operations.hpp>
#include <boost/format.hpp>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // ANSI character format
    cout << boost::format( "%1% %2%" ) % "Hell" % "Low" <<endl;
    string s1 = boost::str( boost::format( "%2% %1%" ) % "Hell" % "Low" );
    cout << s1 << endl;
    // UNICODE character format
    wcout << boost::wformat( L"%s %X" ) % L"-1 is" % -1 << endl;
    wstring s2 = boost::str( boost::wformat( L"%2$s %1$.2f" ) % 3.141592 % L"Version" );
    wcout << s2 << endl;
    // get the path of application(ANSI character set), note:boost::filesystem::path
    string AnsiPath = boost::filesystem::initial_path<boost::filesystem::path>().string();
    cout<<AnsiPath<<endl;
     // get the path of application(unicode character set), note:boost::filesystem::wpath
    wstring UnicodePath = boost::filesystem::initial_path<boost::filesystem::wpath>().string();
    wcout<<UnicodePath<<endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

one compile error occur: obj\Debug\main.o:C:\zjc\PluginFramework\boost_1_42_0\include\boost-1_42\boost\filesystem\operations.hpp|530|undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::get_current_path_api(std::string&)'|
     I have added the the library  at linker option:

boost_system-mgw44-mt-d-1_42.lib

libboost_system-mgw44-sd-1_42.lib

boost_system-mgw44-d.lib

boost_system-mgw44-d-1_42.lib

boost_system-mgw44-mt-d-1_42.lib

the macros:

BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK

BOOST_SYSTEM_NO_LIB

BOOST_SYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED

_DEBUG

_CONSOLE

BOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION

BOOST_FILESYSTEM_DYN_LINK

BOOST_LIB_DIAGNOSTIC

I search the internet.the solution is linking the boost filesystem library.but i have linked the library. My Environment： Win 7 Home version, Code::Blocks V 10.05.

Answer (score 10):

The Boost filesystem library is one of the linkable (and not header only) libraries included. Just add "boost_filesystem" before "boost_system".

If everything is set up the right way, you shouldn't have to add the libraries yourself:
Don't set `BOOST_SYSTEM_NO_LIB`/`BOOST_FILESYSTEM_NO_LIB` unless you really have to. If it isn't set, the headers should handle the dependencies for you.

The macros with `BOOST_..._DYN_LINK` will cause the headers to try to link the shared libraries (which you deactivated with the other macros).

Just one more note: If you'd like to add the libs by hand. Don't mix them and only add one variant each, which you need, and pick the right one (e.g. multithreaded debug "mt-d").